# Dailymotion upload error "no content"

Tags: java, dailymotion-api

I'm developping a web application capable of upload video on Dailymotion all  was find during 1 years and i have seen an error recently occuring when i upload a video on Dailymotion.

```
{
"error": "missing content"
"seal": "540f4ad5a0f9c6a7e85a46be98361581"
}
```

I use java and the lib "org.apache.http" for doing my call on dailymotion.

my code look like this :

```
Path temp = Files.createTempFile(multipartFile.getName(), "." + suffix);
            multipartFile.transferTo(temp.toFile());
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            builder.addPart(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename(), new FileBody(temp.toFile(),
                    ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
            httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());
            try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
                    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                DailymotionUploadVideoResponse dmUploadResponse = mapper.readValue(entity.getContent(),
                        DailymotionUploadVideoResponse.class);
                // Delete temp file after upload
                Files.deleteIfExists(temp);
                if (dmUploadResponse.getError() != null) {
                    throw new DailymotionJsonException(dmUploadResponse.getError().getMessage());
                }
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                response.close();
```

POST on url retrieve by dailymotion :

```
http://upload-12.dc3.dailymotion.com/upload?uuid=035e365c5b2355616e381f43c1b2b391&seal=edad1d3ad9e348c65e975582571e5815
```

Header of the POST request :

```
Content-Disposition:
form-data; 
name="2015-07-16-192550-1.webm"; 
filename="2015-07-16-192550-1.webm", 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream, 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

I don't understand why i'm doing wrong.

I test via curl and i have the same error.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryImx1443wQZZBF0Fb
Content-Length: 1398401
Source message

POST /upload?uuid=035e365c5b2355616e381f43c1b2b391&seal=edad1d3ad9e348c65e975582571e5815 HTTP/1.1
 HOST: upload-12.dc3.dailymotion.com
 content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryImx1443wQZZBF0Fb
 content-length: 1398401

 ------WebKitFormBoundaryImx1443wQZZBF0Fb
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="2015-07-16-192550-1.webm"; filename="2015-07-16-192550-1.webm"
 Content-Type: video/webm
```

Comment: Fix API dailymotion have changed, change the code builder.addPart(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename(), new FileBody(temp.toFile(),
                    ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));

Answer (score 0):

API dailymotion have changed, change the code

```
builder.addPart(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename(), new FileBody(temp.toFile(),
                    ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
```

by :

```
builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(temp.toFile(),
                        ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
```